# Editing a column in a text file using shell script

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a text file:

```
a b n
d f h 
e f y
```

I want to edit it and make it like:

```
a b@gmail.com n
d f@gmail.com h 
e f@gmail.com y
```

How can I do this? Is there any command which can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this awk one liner:

```
$ awk '$2=$2"@gmail.com"' file
a b@gmail.com n
d f@gmail.com h
e f@gmail.com y
```

Comment: +1 The funny thing is some people will look at how simple this is and how complicated the sed alternative is and then choose the sed command anyway because some versions of sed support `-i`. Sigh.... Anyway - newer versions of `gawk` support `-i inedit` to change the original file too if that's a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed inline`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(^[^ ]* *\)\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)$/\1\2@gmail.com\3/' file
```

This will save the changes in the original file itself.

Comment: please explain the regular expression

Comment: `[^ ]*` means match anything except a space and `.*` means any 0 or more length text.

Comment: `sed -r 's/^\S+\s+\S+/&@gmail.com/' file` is more readable and robust *(GNU sed)*.

Comment: This does not make the changes in the original file.  It creates a new file and then gives it the same name as the original.  This is a significant distinction if the original file has other links. It is also not valid in all implementations of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/\S\+/&@gmail.com/2' file
```